# WhatsApp won't send messages

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

I hope this is the right place to ask.
when I click on send button in WhatsApp it is not responding.
I tried:

- restarting the device.
- reinstalling WhatsApp.
- delete WhatsApp cache

I'm using nexus 4 with android 5.11

Comment: Did you install any updates between the last time WhatsApp was working and when it stopped working?

Answer (score -1):

problem solved. I did SMS authentication again

Comment: Did you come to know the reason behind the issue?